# How to evenly distribute offset depending on CFrame.Rotation

Tags: lua, roblox

(Roblox Studio)
I have a code that passes the "Rotation" of the camera to the object. But due to the fact that the center of the rotation of the object is in the center of the object, I have to adjust it via Vector3 offset. the object must be in front of the player all the time. but due to the fact that offset is indicated in one direction, a bug occurs. the object moves out of its place.

How to calculate offset depending on rotation.

```
 local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
 local camera = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera
 local part = game.Workspace:WaitForChild("radCam")
 local offset = Vector3.new(0, 0, -229.8)

 while wait(5) do
     local newPosition = camera.CFrame.Position + offset
     part.CFrame = CFrame.new(newPosition, newPosition + camera.CFrame.LookVector)

     part.CFrame = part.CFrame * CFrame.Angles(0, math.rad(0), 0)
 end
```

I tried to find some formula by which offset can be calculated, but I didn't find anything